# Elasticache - Increase the nodes for replication

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I was looking at elasticache as a replacement for our EC2 redis deployment.
However I have a hard requirement of 1 master and 11 replicas in our deployment, while elasticache allows only 5 replicas. Is there a way this restriction can be relaxed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately 5 read replicas appears to be the upper limit - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Replication.html

Is your replica requirement to spread out CPU load? If so, there are some very capable instances available these days. Check out the M4 family of machines.